# Do I have to supply FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET

Tags: php, facebook

I started developing and application on facebook. In the appinfo.php file should I replace FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET with my own apps ID's or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to supply your app's FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET.